# Rich faces - rich:column next row

Tags: row, richfaces, nested-table

I have a rich data table with 6 rich columns. The first rich column has expand-collapse icon. The sixth rich column is a datatable. I want the sixth rich:column to be displayed in a new row?

- Sandeep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well a breakBefore = true attribute on the 6th rich:column helped. I am able to get the next column in a new row. However, the header of this column is still showing up. Any thoughts on this. Will investigate and add the solution as a comment.